# Как сохранить переменную?

Tags: python

Мой скрипт состоит из парсинга и чат-бота. Парсинг занимает около 10 секунд, в течение
которых пользователь ждет. Так вопрос: как лучше оформить скрипт, в котором после выполнения парсинга полученная в итоге переменная(в моем случае словарь) сохранялся в какой-то файл или как-то еще,чтобы на следующий запуск скрипта не нужно было снова запускать парсинг, а просто
закоментировать парсинг и использовать переменную.

Comment: Ну, просто взять и написать код для работы с файлом? Непонятно в чём у вас сложность возникла

Comment: Не, в файл можно только сохранять строку, а у меня словарь

Comment: Преобразуйте словарь в строку любым удобным способом (например [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)), а при чтении файла преобразуйте строку обратно в словарь

Comment: Точно, спасибо.